# from PIL import Image - ImportError: No module named PIL

Tags: python, macos, module, python-imaging-library

I know there are a number of questions already on stackoverflow related to this issue and I have read them all, but still I am having no success with this issue. I am hoping somebody can help me out with this.

I have installed and reinstalled Pillow 10 times now. I have updated my .bash_profile. Still, I get the same error message.

This is my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
```

This is my code:

```
import sys
import string
import re
from PIL import Image
```

It chokes on the 4th line every time with the message: ImportError: No module named PIL. I have also tried replacing the fourth line with

```
import Image
```

also with no success. I know there are many questions similar to this one on here but believe me I have been reading the answers on those with no success so I'm hoping somebody here can help me with my particular situation. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know, for sure, that you have PIL installed?  Is it installed at a standard location?  If not, did you add the location to your PYTHONPATH?  (For imports, python does not use PATH, it uses PYTHONPATH.)

Comment: Did you install Pillow using pip? If so, what does `pip freeze | grep Pillow` print?

Comment: PM 2Ring, I get the following output: pip freeze | grep Pillow

Comment: oops, forgot to copy, this is what I got: Pillow==2.6.1

Comment: In response to John1024, I know for sure I have Pillow installed. I installed using pip without specifying a directory so I would assume it is in the same location as all other modules. Does your answer mean I should change instances of PATH in my bash_profile to PYTHONPATH? thanks.

Comment: Ok. pip says pillow is installed, but just to double-check that it's in the right place, look in the '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/' directory. There should be 'PIL/' and 'Pillow-2.6.1.egg-info/' directories. Also, run `python -c ""import sys;print sys.path"` in the shell and make sure the Python path contains '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/'.

Comment: Try installing python from `brew`(_if you are on `OSX`. I had a similar kind of error until i used `Pillow` inside my code_). And check if python and pip are running from `brew`'s version.  After installing brew, i was able to use pip install without `sudo`

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31982615/3869739) helps,

Comment: Did you try this ```pip install image```?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was experiencing a similar issue. Fixed it by pip installing WITHOUT sudo.

```
pip install pillow
```

instead of

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

Comment: @YumYumYum Write `py -m pip install pillow` on Windows

Comment: For me the opposite worked. I had to run a script with `sudo` (so I had to install WITH sudo instead of without it). I asume it has to do with which 'home' directory is used to find modules. If run ***with*** sudo it is installed for the `/root` home directory. If sudo is not used, it uses the current user's home directory (`/home/my-usr`). Thus causing the 'module not found', because sudo commands looks into the /root directory while non-sudo look into the current user's directory. Or so I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this while installing tensorflow code on NVIDIA Jetson Nano. This works for me:

```
    pip3 install Image
```

Comment: This is worked on Jetson Nano Dev Kit